# Sql server: Insert

Tags: sql-server, insert

How do i insert the results of the below query into table A which is same format as the query results?

I have tried 'Insert into' but get a error.
Error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'with'. Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an
>   xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a semicolon

.

```
with RowNumbers (RowNum, name, [status], [DateTime])
as
(
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by [DateTime]),
        name,
        [status],
        [DateTime]
    from @T
)
select
    T1.name,
    case T1.[status]
        when 0 then 'In'
        when 1 then 'Out'
        when 2 then 'Absent'
      end as [status],
    sum(datediff(MINUTE, T1.[DateTime], T2.[DateTime]) / 60.0) as [hours]
from RowNumbers T1
    inner join RowNumbers T2
        on T1.RowNum = T2.RowNum - 1 -- joins the current row to the next one
        and T1.name = T2.name
group by T1.name, T1.[status]
order by T1.Name, T1.[status]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Insert into TableName
(select
    T1.name,
    case T1.[status]
        when 0 then 'In'
        when 1 then 'Out'
        when 2 then 'Absent'
      end as [status],
    sum(datediff(MINUTE, T1.[DateTime], T2.[DateTime]) / 60.0) as [hours]
from (select
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by [DateTime]),
        name,
        [status],
        [DateTime]
    from @T)T1
    inner join RowNumbers T2
        on T1.RowNum = T2.RowNum - 1 -- joins the current row to the next one
        and T1.name = T2.name
group by T1.name, T1.[status]
order by T1.Name, T1.[status])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried `insert into` - but *where* did you try it? It should be:

```
;with RowNumbers (RowNum, name, [status], [DateTime])
as
(
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by [DateTime]),
        name,
        [status],
        [DateTime]
    from @T
)

insert into tableA (name,status,hours) --This line is new

select
    T1.name,
    case T1.[status]
        when 0 then 'In'
        when 1 then 'Out'
        when 2 then 'Absent'
      end as [status],
    sum(datediff(MINUTE, T1.[DateTime], T2.[DateTime]) / 60.0) as [hours]
from RowNumbers T1
    inner join RowNumbers T2
        on T1.RowNum = T2.RowNum - 1 -- joins the current row to the next one
        and T1.name = T2.name
group by T1.name, T1.[status]
order by T1.Name, T1.[status]);
```

Comment: Hey I tried inserting it before th e'with' statement which i know now is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Got it - thanks for everyones help on this, see the following link for refernece oin exactly same issue.

```
;with RowNumbers (RowNum, name, [status], [DateTime])
as
(
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by [DateTime]),
        name,
        [status],
        [DateTime]
    from @T
)
INSERT INTO Cost(Name, [Status], [Hours])
select
    T1.name,
    case T1.[status]
        when 0 then 'In'
        when 1 then 'Out'
        when 2 then 'Absent'
      end as [status],
    datediff(MINUTE, 0, T2.[DateTime]-T1.[DateTime]) / 60.0 as [hours]
from RowNumbers T1
    inner join RowNumbers T2
        on T1.RowNum = T2.RowNum - 1 -- joins the current row to the next one
        and T1.name = T2.name
order by T1.Name, T1.[status];
```